# Здравствуйте! Почему функция delete_el не срабатывает?

Tags: java

```
public class MyArray<T> {
    private Object[] arr = {};
    public int size;

    public MyArray() {
        arr = new Object[0];
    }

    public MyArray(T... arr) {
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    public MyArray(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        arr = new Object[size];
    }

    public int size() {
        return arr.length;
    }

    public T get(int i) {
        return (T) arr[i];
    }

    public void set(int i, T t) {
        arr[i] = t;
    }

    public void add(T t) {
        Object[] temp = new Object[arr.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, temp, 0, arr.length);
        arr = temp;
        arr[arr.length - 1] = t;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(arr);
    }

    public void add_end(T el) {
        Object[] temp = new Object[arr.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            temp[i] = arr[i];
        }
        temp[temp.length - 1] = el;
        arr = temp;
    }

    /*public void delete() {
        Object []temp = new Object [arr.length-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
            temp[i] = arr[i];
        arr = temp;
    }*/
    public boolean delete_el(T key) {
        size = arr.length;
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (key == arr[j]) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == size()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            for (int k = j; k < size - 1; k++) {
                arr[k] = arr[k + 1];
            }
            size--;
            arr[arr.length - 1] = 0;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyArray<String> a = new MyArray<String>("1", "2");
        String s = a.get(a.size() - 1);
        System.out.println(s);     // 2
        a.set(1, "New");
        a.add_end("New2");
        System.out.println(a);     // 1 New
        MyArray<Double> b = new MyArray<Double>(3);
        b.set(0, 1.0);
        b.set(1, 2.0);
        b.set(2, 4.0);
        b.add(8.0);
        b.add_end(12.0);
        //b.delete();
        b.delete_el(2.0);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: **if (j == size())** это компилируется? size вроде переменная

Comment: @tilin это метод

Comment: Точно метод. Именовать методы и переменные одинакого - это зло

Answer (score 4):

Вы два объекта `Double` сравниваете через оператор `==`
В этом случае сравниваются ссылки двух объектов, но не их значения. Используйте метод `equals`
Вот так будет удалять:

```
public boolean delete_el(T key){
    size = arr.length;
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        if (key.equals(arr[j]))
            break;
    if (j == size())
        return false;
    else{
        for (int k = j; k < size - 1; k++)
            arr[k] = arr[k+1];
        size--;
        arr[arr.length - 1] = 0;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Это потому что Double - это class? А если у автора заменить использование Double на встроенный тип double, то код автора работал бы без изменений?

Comment: @tilin его класс дженерализован, поэтому в принципе не может иметь внутри простой тип. Дженерик T - это объект

Comment: спасибо большое, сработало.